# delphi a good schema for high i/o usage

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

i have a program that uses 5 serial port for get data from hardware and save them in MySQL database and also transfer them to a third place with tcp/ip

for serial ports i use Async so the have separated threads.so thay cant make the system ui lagy.but if i use MySQL connection in threads created by serial port component it waste the time to read from buffer and make buffer over-load error

on the other hand if i send data process and MySQL store to an anonymous thread it cause a many working threads in queue...

what is best way to handle this kind of apps?

Comment: it seems really hard to explain something to SO guys these days.my question is completely clear.i have problem with high load due to a lot of working threads.

Comment: It's even harder to come up with an answer with so little information, and/or an example of what is being attempted

Comment: This question is completely unclear.

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that your database connection is much slower at transferring data than your serial port is at transferring data. Your solution is to build a stack and work with database writes that are slow.

Comment: @nolaspeaker yes,due to 5 serial port sending data same time and processing them i have lag in processing buffer data...

Comment: If you can't speed up the database connection or slow down the serial port(s), then you need a "buffer" (FIFO stack) that the port(s) can keep pushing items on the top, while the database connection keeps popping items off the "bottom". I've used a `TArray<String>` for this sort of thing in my apps.

Comment: this mean save data in a dynamic array and process data from oldest ? TArray<String> located in the ram !?  please submit this as answer to save in history.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you have described is resolvable by setting FIFO Queue between COM ports and MySQL threads. There is some data flow (name it upstream) from COM devices, put this data to Thread-safe FIFO (Delphi has one implementation: System.Generics.Collections.TThreadedQueue) and allocate N threads for MySQL that will read data portion from FIFO Queue (name it downstream). So you convert you problem to classic Producer/Consumer task. If MySQL threads are too slow, FIFO size will grow, you have to grow number of MySQL threads in this case. You can detect optimal MySQL threads count by viewing FIFO avg size.

Problem of driver buffer over-load is caused in case when physical device write data more quickly than your program can process that data. In your case it happens due to slowness of MySQL thread part.

Truth be told, COM port speed is very slow compared to CPU and Threads, I am sure core of your problem - you read from COM devices large count of little size data-pieces and wrap every one little data piece to SQL operation in background of your MySQL library. Shift your look to BATCHING - combine big count of low size datas to more large data batches, so you can decrease amount of SQL operations over TCP/IP

Comment: You can discover COM device implementation in Aio.pas of my Delphi framework https://github.com/Purik/AIO  This framework can help rid of multithreading for I/O operations. It use Overlapped async API of models operating systems

Comment: Thank you for your complete explanation,